# Symfony2 - FPNTagBundle - Doctrine Extensions

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to wrap my head around an issue with the FPNTagBundle. This is an integration of DoctrineExtensions-Taggable. I have setup everything as described in the installation instructions and the tagging is working, both saving and loading.

I am now trying to load all resources for a given tag/tag_type and am running into some issues.

In DoctrineExtensions-Taggable there is a `TagRepository.php` with the following method:

```
/**
* Returns an array of ids (e.g. Post ids) for a given taggable
* type that have the given tag
*/
public function getResourceIdsForTag($taggableType, $tag)
```

My Tag entity `extends \FPN\TagBundle\Entity\Tag;`

The FPN\Tag Entity `extends DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\Entity\Tag`

When I call the following:

```
$tagRepo = $em->getRepository('SixStringPearBundle:Tag');
$ids = $tagRepo->getResourceIdsForTag('icon_type', $tag);
```

I get the following error:

```
Undefined method 'getResourceIdsForTag'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!
```

If I change this to: `$em->getRepository('DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\Entity\Tag');`

I get the following error:
`The class 'DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\Entity\Tag' was not found in the chain configured namespaces SixString\PearBundle\Entity, FOS\UserBundle\Entity, FPN\TagBundle\Entity`

Is there a way to access this repository? I could simply create a new Repo in my Bundle and copy the code but I feel there's better way.

Also, Why was the class not found in my bundle? It loaded find inside of the FPN Tag Class `extends`

Comment: Might be an error in the entity's annotations or xml metadata, whichever you used. Are you able to confirm what `$tagRepo` is an instance of?

Comment: I was able to add: @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\Entity\TagRepository") to my `Tag` Entity and it seemed to work out! Still not sure why I can reference the DoctrineExtensions here but not inside a controller calling `$em->getRepository('\DoctrineExtensions...')`